# Can't customize the hoverinfo in plotly plot created with sf object

Tags: r, plotly

Here is the code I am using from the tutorial here https://blog.cpsievert.me/2018/03/30/visualizing-geo-spatial-data-with-sf-and-plotly/:

```
library(plotly)
data(franconia, package = "mapview")

plot_ly(
  franconia,
  split = ~NUTS_ID,
  color = ~district,
  stroke = I("black"),
  text = ~paste("This is text and",NAME_ASCI, "\n is in", district), 
  hoverinfo = "text",
  hoveron = "fill"
)
```

I want the text in the hover tooltip to be the `text` attribute. However, when I run this, the text in the hover tooltip is the `split` attribute.

[image]

Comment: Try changing `"fill"` to `"fills"`.

Comment: @margusl Wow! Thank you so much! How did you come up with this, I couldn't find this option in the documentation :). Btw feel free to post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `hoveron` value should be `"fills"`:

```r
library(plotly)
data(franconia, package = "mapview")

plot_ly(
  franconia,
  split = ~NUTS_ID,
  color = ~district,
  stroke = I("black"),
  text = ~paste("This is text and",NAME_ASCI, "\n is in", district), 
  hoverinfo = "text",
  hoveron = "fills"
)
#> No trace type specified:
#>   Based on info supplied, a 'scatter' trace seems appropriate.
#>   Read more about this trace type -> https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter
```

[image]

There are quite a few `hoveron = "fill"` references out there, I guess this is something that has changed at some point, though there are also up to date examples like https://plotly-r.com/maps#cb63-1 .

In this particular case the `No trace type specified` notice and a link to reference is quite handy. Well, the single page ref can get confusing for searching, so this variant is bit better - https://plotly.com/r/reference/scatter/#scatter-hoveron . And it lists `"points"`, `"fills"`, `"points+fills"` as available options.

I don't know such syntax details by heart, but not so long ago I had my own
Plotlyl struggles and from that session recalled something about *"/../ fill and fills behaving differently /../"* . It was this issue - https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1260.